# Android HWUI error when fetching data and show it on list.Builder on flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

after debuging my app ... so i fetch data from server successfully and start to show it in my screen it show this error i don't know how i should do

and i have column with this name "isSurface(**name**=null)" i see it with debug and it not null

```
W/ViewRootImpl[Toast](27344): EGLdebug relayoutWindow Surface isSurface(name=null)  (appName =com.topfood.restauarnt_app) ( mSurfaceControllerIsValid =false) (mNativeObject  =0)/@0x8a6572,viewVisibility is0
W/ViewRootImpl[Toast](27344): EGLdebug relayoutWindow Surface isSurface(name=null)  (appName =com.topfood.restauarnt_app) ( mSurfaceControllerIsValid =true) (mNativeObject  =7b9a633000)/@0x8a6572,relayoutResult is7
W/ViewRootImpl[Toast](27344): EGLdebug Surface isSurface(name=null)  (appName =com.topfood.restauarnt_app) ( mSurfaceControllerIsValid =true) (mNativeObject  =7b9a633000)/@0x8a6572
D/OpenGLRenderer(27344):   HWUI Binary is  disabled
```

Comment: Show your code please so I can help solve the bug

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NidDUEAO1WMHlGKiV2BUaoTBznwd1UIp/view?usp=sharing     this my screen and i have some models